# Convert String^ of zeros and ones (for ex.:"10110110") to hexadecimal byte (i.e. 0x0D) in Visual C++ .NET

Tags: .net, visual-c++

Need to send via serial port to a microcontroller a sequence of bytes. All of the data are collected from multiple numeric up-down and combobox components, where "switch-case" code is implemented.

In the end, I have a string with all the necessary data, which looks like this:
"00011101000000010000001000001000001100100000".
Also have defined byte array with 8 elements, first 2 are the specific sequence to send to the microcontroller (command), then will follow the 6 bytes of data.

I am splitting this string into chunks with 8 symbols. like: "00011101" (the first one).
Can't find a way to convert these chunks into hexadecimal bytes like 0x0d, which I will be able to add to the byte array.

Tried:
`Byte z=Byte::Parse(string)`
But if the string represents a value bigger than 127 (dec), there exception is thrown.

**System.OverflowException: 'Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.'**

I work with Visual Studio, Visual C++ and .NET all 2 days already, so please, do not kick me hard.

Comment: `Byte z = Convert::ToByte(string, 2)`

Comment: Yes, this works, but with many 
 warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'short' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
If this is not dangerous (my data in string represent max value of 63), I am ok